# Integrating Python and MongoDB through Mongoengine

Tags: python, mongodb, python-3.x, mongoengine

I'm learning how to integrate Python and MongoDB, so I set myself a challenge: create a small program to register football players.

My program has two modules, info_player and info_team. I'll run the program interactively (python -i). The first module receives information about the players and the second, information about the team, as well as some queries and saves in database.

I designed my db as follows, database is called "championship", the collections are the "teams" and the documents are the "players". In other words, there is a one-to-many relationship between teams and players.

My questions: do I need to convert objects to Json (thought `to_json` method)? How to save and make some queries?

info_player:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, age, nationality="brazilian", team):
        """
        initializating Jogador class
        """
        self.personal(name, age, country)
        self.professional(team)

    def personal(self, name, age, nationality, dominancy, height):
        """
        personal data about players
        """
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.nationality = nationality
        self.height = height
        self.dominancy = dominancy  # righty, lefty or ambidextrous

    def profissional(self, position, number, team, primary):
        """ 
        professional data about players
        """
        self.position = position
        self.number = number
        self.team = team
        self.primary = False  # is he a regular member of a team?

    def to_Json():
        pass
```

info_team:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from info_player import Player


class TeamDB:
    def __init___(self, nome, fundacao, federacao):
        self.name = name
        self.foundationData = foundationData
        self.federation = federation

    def initializeDB():
        client = MongoClient('localhost', 27017)
        global base
        base = client.league

    def toMongo():
        """
        receive a player object and save it 
        """
    def playersByPosition():
        """
        query players by position
        """
    def lineup():
        """
        receive a team and return its starting line-up, players with primary = true
        """
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> do I need to convert objects to Json (thought to_json method)?

No you don't have to. In the context of your question of saving documents, you can just called [.save()](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.base.datastructures.EmbeddedDocumentList.save) This is because the underlaying MongoEngine converts the object to BSON, so that you don't have to explicitly write a method to convert it to JSON.

See [MongoEngine: Converting mongoengine objects to JSON #1](https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/1)
 if you would like to see how you could convert your MongoEngine object to JSON.

> How to save and make some queries?

See an insert example [MongoEngine Tutorial: Adding to our tumblelog](http://docs.mongoengine.org/tutorial.html#adding-data-to-our-tumblelog):

```
p1 = Player(name='Caio', age=20)
p1.save()
```

Or for query: [Retrieving Type Specific Information](http://docs.mongoengine.org/tutorial.html#retrieving-type-specific-information).